# Can I perform mathematics on a selection in Sublime Text?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext2, sublimetext

Short of writing my own plugin to do so, does there exist a mechanism with which I can add/subtract from multiple selected numbers?

I need to apply the same equation (in this case, subtract 5) to many values; and I'd rather not do it individually. Could this perhaps be a job for another program?

Comment: If you write a plugin, please post a copy here.  I'm always adding up out-of-pocket costs and hours of services rendered.  It would be nice not to have to use Excel in conjunction with ST2.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you already use Emmet (which I highly suggest), use its [Evaluate Math function](http://docs.emmet.io/actions/evaluate-math/). No need to install more plugins. Only issue is that it cuts the result at 2 decimal digits.

Answer (score 5):

There's plugin called [Sublime-Evaluate](https://github.com/jbrooksuk/Sublime-Evaluate) which allows you to evaluate bits of Python, and output it straight into your buffer. For example, `[i for i in range(5)]` evaluated turns itself into `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`. That can be used for arithmetic operations as well, just use those multiple selections and write +5 after each value, then select it all and evaluate. The plugin usually screws positions of your cursors, don't get confused by that.

Answer (score 5):

Sublime Calculate evaluates selected text, and looks great for small calculations, especially paired with the `replace` option: https://github.com/colinta/SublimeCalculate

As stated before, Sublime Evaluate has python evaluation covered: https://github.com/jbrooksuk/Sublime-Evaluate

Comment: Sublime Calculate worked for me. I needed to get the average a few numbers and running Calculate from the Command Palette on the following got me the value:   `avg([13.32,15.13,18.96,45.07,37.34,48.10,34.04])` which was: `30.279999999999998`

Answer (score 2):

Saw this yesterday and thought I would take a shot at it. Basically does the same thing as the Sublime-Evaluate (to bad I didn't see that earlier, could have saved some time). Anyways, the benefit of mine is it allows you to predefine python snippets to run. It also does some variable substitution of the content selected by the cursor. It doesn't do any expansion so you will have to select the content to insert. I was thinking of creating a setting to modify the word separator for the plugin, but hadn't decided yet. If you have an opinion on it, let me know.

https://github.com/skuroda/EvalInsert